# Cannot open input file 'ittnotify.lib'

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-2019, realsense

I'm working with LibRealSense and openCV libraries with VisualStudio 2019, C++ project on Windows 10. I'm trying to work with the example "CustomCalibrationTest"inlcuded into the "CalibrationToolAPI".
I've linked all the libraries into the project and all the "include" path and library directories. But when I try to build it, this error appear:

"Severity Code Description Project File Line Deletion status Error LNK1181 cannot open input file 'ittnotify.lib' CustomCalibrationTest C: \ Program Files \ Intel \ CalibrationToolAPI \ 2.11.0.0 \ api \ DynamicCalibrationAPI \ 2.11.0.0 \ examples \ CustomCalibration \ LINK 1".

I've noticed that "ittnotify" is located in 3rdparty folder in openCV library: i find its ".lib" file into the path: "3rdlibrary/lib", but I can't find its "include" folder, could be this the problem?.
When I built openCV library with CMake I had no errors.
Please help me,
Thank You!

Comment: You get a linker error, your linker can't find the library. Check if the path to the library is in the Additional Library paths property of your project.

Answer (score 0):

This error means the linker could not find ittnotify.lib because it does not exist or the path was not found.

I suggest you to check if you have added the path of the .lib file to the Additional Library Directories (property -> linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories) and if you have added the name of the .lib file with its extension to Additional Dependencies (property -> linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies)

The error can also happen when the LIBPATH contains spaces. If that's the case, move the library to a path without spaces or put quotation marks around the path.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Linker Tools Error LNK1181](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1181?view=msvc-160).

Best Regards,

Jeanine Zhang

Comment: @Emanuele Cinesi Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.
Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.